# Querying nested Json with SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have this content in a table in a column `JsonResponse`:

```
{
  "results": {
    "meta": {
      "number_of_node": 2
    },
    "data": {
      "Node": [
        {
          "id": "44511",
          "subject": 31366
        },
        {
          "id": "72176",
          "subject": 36508
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to extract ALL the "subject"; here my query:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE(JSonResponse, '$.results.data.Node.subject') AS JsonResponse
FROM
    Table
```

but the query result is always `null`.

I didn't find documentation about querying nested Json, any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have a look at [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 has no support for JSON. There are workarounds/hacks, but they're all painful. The best approach if you can't upgrade (which is recommended, since SQL Server 2014 has been out of support for 3 years now) is to leave the JSON parsing to the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    JSonResponse NVARCHAR(MAX)
);
INSERT @Table ( JSonResponse )
VALUES (
'{
  "results": {
        "meta": {
          "number_of_node": 2
        },
        "data": {
          "Node": [
            {
              "id": "44511",
              "subject": 31366
            },
            {
              "id": "72176",
              "subject": 36508
            }
          ]
        }
  }
}'

    );

SELECT oj2.*
FROM @Table AS t
     CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(t.JSonResponse, '$.results')
        WITH ( meta NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON, data NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON ) AS oj
     CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(oj.data, '$.Node')
        WITH ( id INT, subject NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS oj2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need nested `OPENJSON` calls, as you can jump straight to the right path

```sql
SELECT oj.*
FROM @Table AS t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JSonResponse, '$.results.data.Node')
  WITH (
    id int,
    subject int
  ) AS oj;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/lkzjNqFl)

Comment: I've got this: _Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon._

Comment: Are you still running SQL Server 2014? Then this won't work, you should upgrade to a newer version

Comment: I can't  upgrade :(

Comment: Only other option I can think is to write a SQLCLR function that uses Newtonsoft or similar to parse it. Or parse it client-side and send it as a Table Valued Parameter